# How to connect to mongoDB Atlas using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongodb-atlas

I'm trying to connect to my cluster on mongoDB Atlas via Mongoose.connect(), but every time i try to connect i get an exception  "MongoError: authentication fail" 
I know MongoDB Atlas is new mongo as a service could it be not supported by mongoose yet?.

Comment: Can you show the connection string that you're using (but please replace username and password with placeholders). Also, take a look [at this](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/4818).

Comment: 'mongodb://username:<password;>@hcluster0-shard-00-00-he3ln.mongodb.net:27017,hcluster0-shard-00-01-he3ln.mongodb.net:27017,hcluster0-shard-00-02-he3ln.mongodb.net:27017/<hcluster0>?ssl=true&replicaSet=hcluster0-shard-0&authSource=admin'

Comment: Is `<hcluster0‌​>` the actual name of your database? Also, if `password` contains any characters that have a special meaning in URI's (like `@`, `+`, `%`, `/`), you need to encode those.

Comment: Have you added your public IP address to the whitelist?

Comment: Yes it's the actual name(But it's not important I'm using it just for testing, no worries). But I was using mLab before and I didn't have to encode anything. Yes I've added a public IP address to the whitelist.

Comment: Can you verify that you are able to connect using the mongo shell?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongoose with ReplicaSet on Atlas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41213148/mongoose-with-replicaset-on-atlas)

Comment: use directConnection: true, on connect options

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[The answer in this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41214690/3580261) is correct. You should:

- not mix options with connection string (if done so)
- make sure your IP you are running on is whitelisted and your network allows connections to Atlas
- make sure the user has sufficient permissions
- use the connection string **as is** provided by atlas and just provide it to

  ```
  mongoose.connect(uri);
  ```

Comment: Also make sure that you are using the latest mongoose version 

Comment: This works, but special characters need to be typed as literals, [reference](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/troubleshoot-connection/#special-characters-in-connection-string-password). I have found out this problem with my password

Answer (score 20):

**MongoError: authentication fails** - It means your name or password or dbname is not correct -

uri sample -

```
const uri =
    "mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@firstcluster.4rc4s.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
```

Suppose username is - **najim** & password is **1234** & dbname is **pets** (Note  - default dbname is test but you can write whatever you want)  then my uri will be with above credentails -

```
const  mongoAtlasUri =
        "mongodb+srv://najim:1234@firstcluster.4rc4s.mongodb.net/pets?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
```

to connect with moongoose

```
try {
    // Connect to the MongoDB cluster
     mongoose.connect(
      mongoAtlasUri,
      { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true },
      () => console.log(" Mongoose is connected")
    );

  } catch (e) {
    console.log("could not connect");
  }
```

Answer (score 7):

```js
const mongoAtlasUri =
  "mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@firstcluster.4rc4s.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority";

try {
  // Connect to the MongoDB cluster
  mongoose.connect(
    mongoAtlasUri,
    { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true },
    () => console.log(" Mongoose is connected"),
  );
} catch (e) {
  console.log("could not connect");
}

const dbConnection = mongoose.connection;
dbConnection.on("error", (err) => console.log(`Connection error ${err}`));
dbConnection.once("open", () => console.log("Connected to DB!"));
```

Comment: Please, consider adding a note/hint to your code.

Answer (score 5):

```
try {
mongoose.connect( uri, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true}, () =>
console.log("connected"));    
}catch (error) { 
console.log("could not connect");    
}
```

this works fine , try it

Answer (score -2):

"mongodb+srv://:@cluster0.vvkuk.mongodb.net/"
also in the atlas, in security go to  network access, there will be small buttons edit and delete click on edit, and in the edit, there will to two options the first option is ADD CURRENT IP ADRESS & the second option will be ALLOW ACCESS FROM ANYWHERE
go for the first option & then click confirm