How do set up connection with MongoDB atlas and star server?
I have to deploy my application to a live server however I'm not sure how to set it up in a production environment. Should I shut down the server with the process. exit(1) if the connection fails?  I also read about retrying the connection but not sure how I would implement it.
`
const connectDB =  async():  Promise<void> =>{
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL as string);

        logger.info('Successfully connected to the database')
    }catch (error) {
         logger.error('Error connecting to the database:', error);
         process.exit(1);
    }

}

export default connectDB


const app : Express = express()


app.get('/', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    
    
})



// Connection to the DB and start server
connectDB().then(() => {
    app.listen(5001, () => {
        logger.info(`Server is running on porting ${__port__}`)
    })
}).catch((error ) => {
    
    logger.error('Something is wrong :', error);
})




`
Do you guys have any advice on how to improve the current code? Or it should be enough?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43394019/how-to-connect-to-mongodb-atlas-using-mongoose
